# sending props render component separately one more time

Tags: reactjs, react-props

`CalculateResults.js` and `ScoreBox.js` are class components.

I send the result i wanna see in `ScoreBox` form `CalculateResults` like this:

```
CalculateResults.js

render(){
        return(
                <ScoreBox calculate={this.state.calculate} />
        )
}
```

and i get this props in `ScoreBox` like this:

```
ScoreBox.js

render(){
        return (
            <div className="scoreBox d-flex">>
                       <div>
                           <p>score</p>
                           <h2>{this.props.calculate}</h2>
                       </div>
            </div>       
        );
}
```

my problem is that it doesn't update scorebox, it renders another scorebox next to the previous one and shows the result there.

The whole story is like this: Scorebox component exists then When i click a button in `UserMove.js` a boolean called `onlyChooseOne` becomes true and i send some props to CalculateResults.js like this:

```
UserMove.js

render(){
        return(
             <div>
                {
                !onlyChooseOne
                &&
                <CalculateResult number={randomNumber} userChoice={userChoice} />
                }
        )
             </div>
}
```

How should i fix it?

Comment: Can you show the code when clicking a button CalculateResults starts to calculate ?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. It may be you have added new UserRemove instead of update prop for re-render CalculateResult component